# HTML2PDF Not work in hosting, but work in localhost

Tags: php, html2pdf

This my error:

> **Strict Standards**: Declaration of FPDF_Alpha::Image() should be compatible with FPDF::Image($file, $x = NULL, $y = NULL, $w = 0, $h = 0, $type= '', $link = '') in **/home/stekomin/public_html/ujian/html2pdf_v3.31/_mypdf/03_fpdf_alpha.class.php** on line **21**
>
> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/stekomin/public_html/ujian/html2pdf_v3.31/_mypdf/03_fpdf_alpha.class.php: 21) in **/home/stekomin/public_html/ujian/html2pdf_v3.31/_mypdf/03_fpdf_alpha.class.php** on line 1017
>   **FPDF error**: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: Add relevant minimum code required to reproduce the issue otherwise it will be closed by community. If you don't do this within a reasonable duration of time, I am afraid I will have to flag it as such. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should disable to show errors on your production server:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');  
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

The first line disables showing the errors to the user, the second line though enables the logging of these errors.

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

This error occurs because there is already content sent to the user ( your error message ) and FPDF wants to set header information, which must happen before content is sent.